# When using NSNotificationCenter, why must my userInfo be of type [NSObject : AnyObject]?

Tags: swift2, nsnotificationcenter, nsnotifications, userinfo

I am simply trying to pass my WorkoutObject in an NSNotification using Swift 2.0.  Here is my code:

```
let myDict = ["MyWorkout" : myWorkoutObj]
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("WorkoutNotification", object: self, userInfo: myDict)
```

The complier doesn't like myDict because it is in the form of [String:WorkoutObj] instead of [NSObject:AnyObject].  I've tried countless ways of fixing this:

I tried casting my WorkoutObj to AnyObject.  That doesn't solve the problem.

I tried putting ? and or ! around my WorkoutObj. That doesn't solve the problem.

Why can't I pass the object in a form of [String:WorkoutObj]?  And what must I do to make this happen?

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out.

My WorkoutObject was a struct instead of a class.  Once I changed it to a class everything worked.